# Bootstrap Column, 100% height doesnt apply

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, im using bootstrap 3.0, and working on columns, and im having problem with column heights.

My desired output is to have white border in between column, i was able to achieve this on columns with same height, but if the columns is shorter in height, the border is short also,

[image]

I tried setting the columns' height to 100%, but is doesnt work, setting the column's height via exact px (100px) works, but i cant use this since i need the column height to be responsive

Here is my html code

```
            <div class="col-xs-12 bg-8560a9">
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-left border-right-white full-height">Europe Zone 1 (West)</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 border-right-white full-height">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">794 M</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">81.6%</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 full-height">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">833 M</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">83.5%</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css

```
.full-height{height:100% !important;}
```

Comment: Please provide your css

Comment: @captainsac, my other css contains bg color only, i havent put a code that overwrites the grid system's css except for the `.full-height`

Comment: Inspect element ( right click -> Inspect Element) to see whether padding or margin is taking up space or not. Then you'll be able to see what is the original height being applied to element.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, firebug shows `.full-height`'s code which is 100%, no no padding and margin

Comment: then their height is being applied 100% only , you need to check where you're making a mistake. or show us your code on jsfiddle or something.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gx6gagdd/ if you resize the browser, the height being applied to, is based on how many content rows are generated when the contents are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the common Problem that occurs when **parent element don't have there heights set,** height and width don't behave same for Browser,you can skip setting width but for element height this is generic issue

suppose your parent element has `height: auto`; and setting percentage height to children will 
confuse browser to calculate height for element from an undefined value,since it is null so browser will do nothing.

you need to add

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 bg-8560a9 full-height">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-left border-right-white full-   height">Europe Zone 1 (West)</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 border-right-white full-height">
                <div class="col-xs-6">794 M</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">81.6%</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 full-height">
                <div class="col-xs-6">833 M</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">83.5%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this will again work only if parent element height is set,

full reference to this problem is [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm)

So, if you want to set a height on your web pages to a percentage, you have to set the height of every parent element of the one you want the height defined.

Comment: you mean i have to set all the parent elements height?

Comment: So, if you want to set a height on your web pages to a percentage, you have to set the height of every parent element of the one you want the height defined.

Comment: tried it, ive set all parent elements height upto the html and body tag, still wont work

Comment: thanks, http://jsfiddle.net/gx6gagdd/5/ but the the column wont expand vertically to accommodate the contents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80023/discussion-between-shekharpankaj-and-ram-obrero).